# type inference error in the callback

Tags: ios, swift, networking, callback, type-inference

I am having an type inference error that I can't solve. I have attached the most important snippet below. The parsing process is done separately by a `Decoder` in the `APIClient`.

Why doesn't the `APIClient`'s `execute` does not recognise the `T` is the `[Chapter]` as the line `completion(Result.success(decodedData))` is having that type?

[image]

```
func loadFeed(completion: @escaping (Result<[Chapter]>) -> Void) {
    APIClient.shared.execute(APIRequest.loadFeed) { response in

        guard let decodedData = response.decodedData else { return }
        completion(Result.success(decodedData))
    }
}
```

The snippet above is how I call `APIClient` in my `Services` class.

```
class APIClient: APIClientProtocol {
    static let shared = APIClient()
    func execute<T: Decodable>(_ apiRequest: APIRequestDefining,
                               responseDecoder: ResponseDecoder = .jsonDecoding,
                               completionHandler: @escaping (Response<T>) -> Void) {
        var response = Response<T>(request: request, httpResponse: dataResponse.response, data: dataResponse.data)

        do {
            try responseDecoder.decode(response: &response)
        } catch {
            response.error = error
        }

        completionHandler(response)
    }
}



public struct Response<T> {
    var decodedData: T?
}



enum Result<Value> {
    case success(Value)
    case failure(Error)
}
```

**EDIT:**
To clarify, the snippet below is where and how I `decode` the raw response into the object inferred.

```
struct JSONResponseDecoder: ResponseDecoding {
    func decode<T: Decodable>(response: inout Response<T>) throws {
        guard let data = response.data else { return }
        do {
            try response.decodedData = JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            throw(ApplicationError(errorType: .decodingError))
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT!!!!:**

I found a really strange thing, I remove the line with `guard`, it works all fine, why is that?

**Before**:
[image]
**After**:
[image]

Comment: Where would the compiler infer the type from?  There is no other use of that type at the call-site.

Comment: @Avi doesn't `completion(Result.success(decodedData))` do the job? I imagine it would match `decodedData` to the `[Chapter]`.

Comment: The connection is entirely in your head.  There's nothing in the code that connects the specialization of the outer `loadFeed()` call with the call to `execute()`.  `Result<T>` is not all the same type as `Response<T>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the answer through another post.

The cause for the error is the compiler only refers the closure return type when there is a single statement in the closure.

https://forums.swift.org/t/problems-with-closure-type-inference/11859/2

Answer (score 2):

You said, "execute does not recognise the T is the [Chapter]", and I wonder why do you expect so.

You have a loadFeed function, with a completion block that uses the generic type Chapter.

Then you have an execute method with a generic type T. When you call your execute method, it does not know anything about type Chapter.

Example where I get the same error as you:

```
 func execute<T>(completionHandler: @escaping (T) -> Void) {

 }
 self.execute { (result) in
 }
```

The solution is to cast the parameter so that T can be inferred. In your case:

```
func execute<T>(completionHandler: @escaping (T) -> Void) {

 }
 self.execute { (result:[Chapter]) in
 }
```

Generics are amazing :)

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question, can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Your `completionHandler` takes a parameter with a generic type, so be explicit with your type in the closure otherwise it can't infer the type:

```
func loadFeed(completion: @escaping (Result<[Chapter]>) -> Void) {
    APIClient.shared.execute(APIRequest.loadFeed) { (chapters: [Chapter]) -> () in

        guard let decodedData = chapters.decodedData else { return }
        completion(Result.success(decodedData))
    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain that why in my implementation, the line `completion(Result.success(decodedData))` would not infer the `completion: @escaping (Result<[Chapter]>` that the T is `[Chapter]`. So that the `response` knows how itself is been inferred.

Comment: Show me exactly where the `T` becomes `[Chapter]`?

Comment: @crom87 has put it very well: "...you have an execute method with a generic type T. When you call your execute method, it does not know anything about type Chapter."

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question, can you take a look?

Comment: My answer is the same, make your type explicit.

Comment: in my second edit, getting rid of the guard will make the type infer works.... why’s that

Comment: That's because your `loadFeed` closure does provide the type, namely `@escaping (Result<[Chapter]>) -> Void)` then it has no problem inferring it. Meaning if you do nothing else with `response` in your `execute` closure other than pass along to another function which can infer the type, then it sort of ignores the type and doesn't complain. But if you do want to access (not just pass along) `response` you MUST know the type, thus explicitly declare as your closure parameter.